# Why wc_get_template_part() not working inside wc_get_products()?

Tags: woocommerce

Cant find full loop example on the web with  `wc_get_template_part()` and `wc_get_products()`, so looking for help here:

```
            global $woocommerce;
            global $product;
            $args = array(
                'limit' => 15,
                'category' => array('printers', 'laptop')
            );
            $query_cats = wc_get_products($args);

            foreach ($query_cats as $query_cat) {
               
                echo $query_cat->get_id();
                echo $query_cat->get_title();
                // echo "<pre>";
                // var_dump($query_cat);
                wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
            }
            
            ?>
```

Titles and ids are displayed, var_dump also, bu wc_get_template_part - no. I have `add_theme_support('woocommerce')`; and `also body_class()`;

Comment: You should better use a woocommerce shortcode instead…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce content-product.php template only works only with [standard loop(with instance of Wp_Query)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#usage). May be following solution can help:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'tax_query'     => [
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => ['printers', 'laptop'],
      )
    ],
);

$product = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $product->have_posts() ) {
    $product->the_post();

    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it can be done** (2022 update)

If you want to avoid native `WP_Query` or using shortcodes, this actually can be done using `wc_get_products()`.

You just need to **setup and reset postdata** within your foreach loop and **setup WooCommerce loop** properly.

```php
global $post; // Do not forget this!

$args = array(
    'limit' => 15,
    'category' => array('printers', 'laptop')
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

// Set loop properties
wc_set_loop_prop('columns', 5);

// Start custom WC loop
woocommerce_product_loop_start();
foreach( $products as $product ) {

    // Setup postdata
    $post = get_post( $product->get_id() );
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // Get template part
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
}

// End loop and reset postdata
woocommerce_product_loop_end();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Important note:** this will only work if queried products are within any HTML element with the `woocommerce` class (otherwise WooCommerce CSS won't load for your products). In some templates, the `woocommerce` class is already part of the DOM (e.g. `<body>` element), but if it isn't, wrap your loop within an element as such:

```html
<div class="woocommerce my-products-loop">
    <?php // Your loop goes here ?>
</div>
```

***TIP:** You can set various loop properties using `wc_set_loop_prop` in the "Set loop properties" part of the code*